# How to identify that asset added inside Assets.xcassets are used in project?

Tags: swift, xcode, assert

How to identify quick way the Assets added inside Assets.xcassets for Images & color are using inside project or not.

Example:

```
int value = 10
```

In this case int value not used inside application which give an warning.

```
Initialization of immutable value 'value' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
```

What if inside `Assets.xcassets` added color or image are not used how to identify ?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode has no tool which could highlight not used assets but there is a open source project called "[AssetsChecker](https://github.com/freshOS/AssetChecker)" which will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way a tool can know which assets are not being used by your application.

Imagine that you are creating a Weather app, and the data you receive from the server includes the `image_key` that you use to know which asset to load.

If a tool to find unused assets was used, it would tell you that every image or color that is not referenced directly is not used, which would yield a LOT of false positives.

Comment: Okay that is true since loading assert dynamically.